# Reference variables and objects elsewhere in a form

Tags: .net, vb.net, scope

I am trying to pass an equipment object to a form object and then use that equipment object in a click event from a button on the form.  But I don't know how to properly reference the equipment object within the button event.

I set up the new form instance using:

```
Public Sub New(ByRef thisEquip As classEquipment)
    Me.InitializeComponent()
    Me.Text = thisEquip.equipName & " Tests"
End Sub
```

and set up the button click event like this:

```
Private Sub btnUpdateAndClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdateAndClose.Click
    Call updateTestList(thisEquip)
End Sub
```

But the 'thisEquip' object is not recognized.  I think this is because the sender is the button and not the form itself.  However, I don't know how to reference the equipment object from the form.

Comment: `thisEquip` is *passed* to the form in the ctor.  It only exists there unless you save a reference to it in order to use it elsewhere.  It is all about Scope.  [Scope in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx)

Comment: I mistakenly thought that since both were in the same form class module that I could somehow reference it within the button event, similar to the Module discussion in the link you provided.  What is the appropriate way to reference a form object in a button event?  I tried "Me.thisEquip" and creating an separate reference in the constructor like thisFormEquip = thisEquip, but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx) depends on where a variable is declared.  You might have missed something skimming the link - each scope level summary includes the phrase *in which it is declared*.

Now look at your constructor:

```
Public Sub New(ByRef thisEquip As classEquipment)
```

`thisEquip` is **declared** as an argument to the constructor.  Thus, it only exists in that procedure. The fact that the procedure is in a form or that `thisEquip` is mentioned in the form (or module or anything else) is incidental. While it is true that the constructor is special in several ways, in matters of *Scope*, it is just another procedure.

#### Form Level Scope

To save a reference to it for use elsewhere:

```
Public Class Form1
    ' declare a variable to hold the reference
    Private myEquip As classEquipment
    ' declare an array
    Private myImgs As Image()

    Public Sub New(ByRef thisEquip As classEquipment)
        InitializeComponent()
        ...
        myEquip = thisEquip         ' assign param to the var

        ' assign array of images to the Form level var
        ' via a temp array
        myImgs = New Image() {My.Resources.add, 
                              My.Resources.ballblack, My.Resources.ballblue,
                              My.Resources.ballgreen}
    End Sub
```

**Declared** at the form level, it has form/class level scope.  You can now reference `myEquip` or myImgs anywhere in the form.  **Do Not Use** `Dim` when merely assigning something to a form level object - it will create a new local, but identically named variable.

---

Other common scope levels:

#### Procedure Level Scope

```
Private myFoo as Int32

Private Sub DoSomething()
    Dim myBar As String 
    myBar = "Ziggy"
    ...
    Dim myFoo As Int32 = 7
End Sub
```

This is more often called *local scope*.  I am using *procedure level* because it compares and contrasts better to the other terms.

`myBar` is declared in the `DoSomething` method, so it has procedure level scope  - it only exists in that method.  Trying to use it elsewhere will result in an error.  This is similar to the constructor example above with the main difference being that the `thisEquip` object was passed as a parameter rather than declared locally.

This leads some to get confused:  the `Dim myFoo` in the method declares (creates!) a new, local-only `myFoo` variable which has no relation to the Form/Class level variable of the same name.  The local version shadows out the other.  Part of the confusion for this seems to be that some think they need to (re) use `Dim` before they can use a variable.  You do not.

---

#### Block Level Scope

Directly from MSDN:

```
If n < 1291 Then
    Dim cube As Integer
    cube = n ^ 3
End If
```

A fair number of VB statements create a *block scope* (`For Each`/`Next`, `If`/`End If` and `Using`/`End Using`).  Variables declared inside a Block, have a scope limited to that block.  Basically, (almost) anything which results in indentation creates a Block Scope.

```
Private Sub .....
    Dim cube As Int32

    If n < 1291 Then
       cube = n ^ 3
    End If
```

Now, `cube` can be used elsewhere in the procedure: its scope has been changed from Block to Local.

For more details, see MSDN:
 - [Scope In Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx)
 - [Value Types vs Reference Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx)

Comment: That makes sense; my issue was that I wrongly thought that the scope of a constructor applied to that form object while it was active.  I passed thisEquip byRef because I wanted to apply changes to it; but now I am applying changes to myEquip.  Is there a better place to pass thisEquip byRef than in the constructor?

Comment: an object is a reference type (see [Value Types vs Reference Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx) ) so you should be able to make changes to it in that form.  `myEquip` `thisEquip` or `fooEquip` are just handles or pointers  ("references")  to the real object

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  That works fine and the changes stay within the thisEquip object after the form is done with it.  Thank you