# How do I change a DateTime variable's time?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime

New to DateTime and google is sincerely failing me. I'm currently using a DateTime variable to track time in my game.

The problem is, is that any attempt of changing said DateTime is resulting in a "Property [time] is ReadOnly" error. Any help, working alternatives or roundabouts would be appreciated.

```
Sub IncreaseTime(unit As Integer)
    Dim NewDate As DateTime

    With World.WorldTime
        NewDate = New DateTime(.Date.Year, .Date.Month, .Date.Day, .Date.Hour, .Date.Minute, .Date.Second + unit)
        .Date = NewDate
    End With
End Sub
```

Edit #1;

```
   Sub IncreaseTime(unit As Integer)
    Dim NewDate As DateTime

    With World.WorldTime
        NewDate = NewDate.AddSeconds(unit)
        .Date = NewDate
    End With
End Sub
```

Edit #2;

[image]
[image: Image2]

Comment: ALL the properties are read only: Date, Year etc.  `NewDate.AddMinutes(10)` or  `NewDate.AddHours(-1)` to subtract

Comment: Adding to what @Plutonix has said, `.AddMinutes()` and friends will not *change* the value of your `DateTime` variable. Rather, you'll want to assign the new value to your variable, as in `NewDate = NewDate.AddMinutes( 10 )`

Comment: Yes, sorry; I forgot to mention a DateTime is immutable - assign the result to the same or new var.  good catch  @BobKaufman

Comment: Please see my edit - so what would I replace ".date = newdate" to? How do you "Reassign" it as such?

Comment: Re: EDIT -  that `NewDate` is rather pointless - declared locally, it will go out of scope when the method ends.  Your code is correct - the var has *local scope* only.  If you want to use it elsewhere, decalre it outside the sub. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33249045/1070452) explains scope

Comment: Edited again; strangely, I can update NewDate just fine as it's local, but I can't change a public variable in a public class?

Comment: you cant assign a value to hours, minutes, years or date.  The first line (edit 2) creates a NewDate +unit seconds from World.  The second line is FUBAR.  If your plan is to change the datetime of `World` : `WorldDate = WorldDate.AddSeconds(unit)`

Comment: So back to the original question, what am I missing here to update my world.worldtime.date DateTime variable?

Comment: Apologies; still, isn't that exactly what I've done in my FUBAR line? .date = .date.addseconds(unit) ?

Comment: No.  `Date` is an immutable property of a DateTime variable (the leading dot means it is a property).  You cannot assign values to any of them.

Comment: You're kidding me. So it's literally; Sub IncreaseTime(unit As Integer) : World.WorldTime = World.WorldTime.AddSeconds(unit) : End Sub

Comment: If you ask me, you dont need a sub to encapsulate that, but yes, you create a whole new DateTime var when you Addxxx any unit.

Comment: No wonder I couldn't find google results, it's simple. Thanks guys. Do one of you want to post the Answer and we can close it, for future searchers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DateTime`type is **immutable** - all the properties are read-only, so you cannot set the `Date`, `Time` or even a part of them (years, mins etc).

Since none of the properties can be set directly, to change any part of one use one of the methods to `AddSeconds()`, `AddYears()` etc.  These all create and return a new `DateTime` value with the desired adjustment.  To subtract, just use a negative value:

```
WorldDate = WorldDate.AddMinutes(unit)
' to subtract:
WorldDate = WorldDate.AddMinutes(-unit)
```

The result **must** be assigned, either to a new variable or the existing one.

The *reason* is pretty simple: adding n minutes might roll over the `Day` or `Month` as well as other properties like `DayOfYear` or `DayOfWeek`.  Allowing direct access would require lots of checking that the value is legal (like `.Minutes = 67` or `.Day = 33`).

To set the date or time to specific values, create a new one using some of the old values and specifying the other values you want:

```
WorldDate  = New DateTime(WorldDate.Year, WorldDate.Month, WorldDate.Day, 
         myHrs, mySecs, myMins)
```