# vb.net .addhours not changing a datetime variable

Tags: vb.net

My code below fails to change WALRT.

```
    dim WALRT as datetime = latest_weight_average_request_time
dim days_latest_weight_factor = 0.5
dim WALRT_new_hour = WALRT.hour * ( 1 - days_latest_weight_factor) +    last_request_time.hour *  days_latest_weight_factor
WALRT.AddHours( WALRT_new_hour - WALRT.hour  )

WALRT.AddHours( 4 )
```

Comment: It is a function returning a new DateTime var with the new value because [the DateTime type is immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35516322/1070452)

Comment: A part from the simple answer that AddHours doesn't change the source datatime variable but returns the new calculated value. Can you explain what are you trying to do with this code?. It isn't very clear to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why DateTime.AddHours doesn't seem to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781420/why-datetime-addhours-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Answer (score 1):

AddHours returns a new DateTime with the added hours.
It doesn't work modifying directly the variable provided

```
WALRT = WALRT.AddHours(WALRT_new_hour - WALRT.hour).AddHours(4)
```

However your code it is pretty weird because you are simply adding 4 hours to the initial value and all the lines in the middle can be removed.

For example, suppose the value of the Hour property of *latest_weight_average_request_time* is 10.

Your code assigns the same value to *WALRT* so the line that calculates the value of *WALRT_new_hour* is like this

```
dim WALRT_new_hour = 10 * ( 1 - 0.5) + 10 * 0.5 ' => equals to 10
```

and the following line (after fixing it) is

```
WALRT = WALRT.AddHours(10 - 10) ' ??
```

so the final line just add 4 hours to the initial value

```
WALRT = WALRT.AddHours(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.AddHours`returns an new `DateTime` object. So you need to write e.g.

```
WALRT = WALRT.AddHours(4)
```