# Calling global label array from other procedure

Tags: vb.net

The following procedure has worked before, but won't work at all:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

Dim Labels() As Label = New Label() {Label1, Label2, Label3}

end sub

Private Sub Labels_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
        Handles Label1.Click, Label2.Click, label3.Click

    for i = 0 to 2
        Labels(i).BackgroundImage = My.Resources.buttonBselected 'NOT WORKING!!!
    next
end sub
```

It turns "NullReferenceException" message.
How can I declare the labels array global or etc? (VS 2010)

Comment: You need a form level array (its not global).  See  [Reference variables and objects elsewhere in a form](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33248704/1070452)  You declared the array inside form load so that is the only place it exists and/or it isnt the same one as declared elsewhere

Comment: @plutonix, Declaring labels after "Public Class Form1" not working again.

Comment: Well, it wont work until you remove the local declaration in form load.  You should read up on what `Dim / Private / Public` do.