# Fonts instances: how to simplify document creation with different fonts styles

Tags: .net, vb.net, fonts

I create a simple PDF file using iTextSharp. Is working fine.

Now I want the user can change the style or theme. The user choose from a dialog box: Normal, Elegant, Modern and then some fonts of the PDF needs to change to suit the style or theme desired.

The PDF create Sub have something like:

```
'Define fontLetterSeparator
Dim fontLetterSeparator As New Font(BaseFont.CreateFont("c:/windows/fonts/comic.ttf", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED), 18)

'Define letter separator paragraph
Dim letterSeparator As New Chunk(ActualLetter, fontLetterSeparator)
```

Where ActualLetter is just a letter like A, B, C... (reading from the SQLite database, no problem whit this)

One way I think I can manage the 3 styles or themes is with code like

```
If PDFTheme = "Normal" Then
    Dim fontLetterSeparator As New Font(BaseFont.CreateFont("c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED), 20)
End If

If PDFTheme = "Elegant" Then
    Dim fontLetterSeparator As New Font(BaseFont.CreateFont("c:/windows/fonts/verdana.ttf", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED), 20)
End If

If PDFTheme = "Modern" Then
        Dim fontLetterSeparator As New Font(BaseFont.CreateFont("c:/windows/fonts/comic.ttf", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED), 60)
End If
```

But this didn't work, I think is because of font immutable condition. So I think the solution is with 3 new fonts or new instances instead

```
Dim fontLetterSeparatorNormal As New fontLetterSeparator
fontLetterSeparatorNormal.Name = "Arial"

Dim fontLetterSeparatorElegant As New fontLetterSeparator
fontLetterSeparatorElegant.Name = "Verdana"

Dim fontLetterSeparatorModern As New fontLetterSeparator
fontLetterSeparatorModern.Name = "Comic"
```

and so on with the size condition but this makes the original line

```
'Define letter separator paragraph
'Dim letterSeparator As New Chunk(ActualLetter, fontLetterSeparator)
```

more complicated because now I need another block of 3 IF - Then to choose the right font for each style or theme...

**I'm sure there's gonna be a more simple and clean solution but I can´t figure it out**

Comment: I am not exactly sure what the problem is, but you should know that a) *where* you declare (Dim, Private, Public) a variable determines the `scope`; b) everything which results in indentation creates a block scope (second example, those fonts only live inside the If).  You dont need to use new with Dim/Private - you can declare at one level and initialize at another.  Not sure what the problem is with immutability unless it is a mischaracterisation

Comment: @Plutonix Scope!!! I didn´t knew about the scope of a Dim inside a block!

Comment: Since it was an issue of scope I am going to Close this as a dupe of the answer linked to - it wasnt entirely clear that was The Main issue.  The other answer has a more complete answer. Please upvote it if it helps.

Comment: @Plutonix "Please upvote it if it helps." upvoted this comment? Done. The complete answer done too.

Comment: @Plutonix done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If PDFTheme = "Normal" Then
    Dim fontLetterSeparator As New Font(BaseFont.CreateFont("c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED), 20)
End If
```

> But this didn't work, I think is because of font immutable condition.

You did not describe an error, but the code in general seems to be in a battle with itself over scope.  Almost everything which cause code indentation (`If/End If`, `For Each/Next`) results in a new block scope. As a result, *those* font object only exist until the `End If`.

If the issue is that you declared the font variable elsewhere, and you cannot understand it isnt changed, this is why; you are accidentally using 2 different font variables in 2 different scopes.

Also, `New` and `Dim | Private | Public` do **2 different things** and do not have to be used together every time.  `New` *creates the object instance* while the others *declare a variable* (and usually the type) with the `Scope` determined by *where* that declaration is.

```
' first, I would use an Enum for the style
Public Enum PDFSytles
    [Default]                  ' its a reserved word
    Elegant
    Modern
End Enum
...
Private PDFStyle As PDFStyles  ' will default to Default (0)
Private fontLetterSeparator As Font
```

This font variable is simply declared.  Trying to use it will result in a NullReference Exception, *but* because it is declared at the Form/Class level is will be usable anywhere in the form.

```
If fontLetterSeparator IsNot Nothing Then
    fontLetterSeparator.Dispose()
End If 

Select Case PDFStyle 
    Case PDFStyles.Elegant
        fontLetterSeparator = New Font("Verdana"...)
    Case PDFStyles.Modern
        ...
End Select
```

First the code disposes of the old font to prevent leaking resources.  Then it creates a `New` font and assigns it to the variable.  The variable was declared long ago and far away elsewhere in the code so it need not be declared again.

I dont know what SQLite has to do with this or what `New Chunk(...)` does, but the code and part of the description sounds like you are running into a wall with the `Scope`.

More:

- **MSDN: [Scope in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx)**
- **[Reference variables and objects elsewhere in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33248704/1070452)**

---

That said, NET `Font` objects *are* immutable.  But that means you cant change doing something like:

```
myFancyFont.Name = "Elabora Special"
```

Comment: Just a little typo mistake the first "End If" must be "End Enum". 

All the other code works perfect. A really clean solution because it's really easy to add more themes to the code. "the code in general seems to be in a battle with itself over scope", yes that was the case! Now I learned about scope (again!), enums, and more.

fontLetterSeparator.Dispose() is not working, I get a message "Dispose is not a member of Font" maybe is something of iTextSharp because Visual Studio say Form1.fontLetterSeparator As iTextsharp.Text.Font

Comment: Chunk is part of iTextSharp code, not SQlite.

Thanks for the support and the links.

Comment: Fixed the typo - thanks.  `Dispose` is a member of `System.Drawing.Font` a TextSharp Font is something different (and explains the BaseFont.Create syntax).  They must be handling the disposal.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Comment: The first If need the End If and Public Enum need the End Enum, that part still need correction. :)