# Get string as shown in DataGridView

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that uses a DataTable as datasource.

I need to get (as array of string) the values shown in the DataGridView with the same format.

So, in the DataTable there is a field with value "100" shown in the DGV as "€ 100,00". I need to get "€ 100,00" as string

Another field is a double and its value is "31.506849315068493150684931507" shown in the DGV as "€ 31,51". I need to get "€ 31,51" as string

The `DataTable` has fields of various type (string, date, double) and for all of them I need to get a string as shown in the DGV.

I've tried with the below code but I get values of the `DataTable`.

```
For x As Integer = 0 To Me.DGV_IntCalc.RowCount - 1
    Dim RowStrList As New List(Of String)
    For Each Col As String In MaxColLen.Keys
        RowStrList.Add(Me.DGV_IntCalc.Item(Col, x).Value.ToString)
    Next
    Calc_Summay &= String.Format(F_Str, RowStrList.ToArray) & vbCrLf
Next
```

F_Str is a string that gives columns format like "{0,10} {1,20}"

EDIT2:

I also tried:

```
RowStrList.Add(Format(Me.DGV_IntCalc.Item(Col, x).Value, _
               Me.DGV_IntCalc.Columns(Col).DefaultCellStyle.Format))
```

but it didn't give expected result.  I also tried:

```
Dim Str$ = Me.DGV_IntCalc.Item(Col, x).Value.ToString
Dim Frmt$ = Me.DGV_IntCalc.Columns(Col).DefaultCellStyle.Format
Dim FormattedStr$ = Format(Str, Frmt)
```

or

```
Dim FormattedStr$ = String.Format(Str, Frmt)
```

But I get values as in the `DataTable` (not formatted)

Comment: Why don't u simply use `.Value` instead of `.Value.toString`  ?

Comment: You've got your arguments to `String.Format` transposed in your edit.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I tried both `Format` and `String.Format` with respective syntax but I'm still getting errors.

Comment: @genespos I can't see the error messages on your screen from over here.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I don't get runtime errors I get wrong results: I get values as in the DataTable or sometimes get Format string (i.e. "p2") instead of the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DGV provides a view of the data which includes formatting.  Somewhere you tell it to format that one column as currency.  Maybe something like this:

```
dgv1.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2"
```

To get back those formatted values, use the `FormattedValue` property:

```
For n As Int32 = 0 To dgv1.Rows.Count - 1
    Console.WriteLine(dgv1.Item(n, 3).FormattedValue)
Next
```

Also note that in your code, you declare your List inside the `If`:

```
For x As Integer = 0 To Me.DGV_IntCalc.RowCount - 1
    Dim RowStrList As New List(Of String)
    For Each Col As String In MaxColLen.Keys
        RowStrList.Add(Me.DGV_IntCalc.Item(Col, x).Value.ToString)
    Next
    Calc_Summay &= String.Format(F_Str, RowStrList.ToArray) & vbCrLf
Next
```

Since `RowStrList` is declared inside the `If` block, it will only exist there.  Everything which results in indentation also creates a new Block Scope.  See: [Reference variables and objects elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33249045/1070452) for more info

Comment: I've declared `RowStrList` this way because I need it only here. Anyway I'll check my code to be sure that everything works as espected. Thanks

Comment: Yes, if you just need it in the block to create that string, you are fine - it wasnt clear if that was all it was intended for.