# Passing the value of something from the sub main() to another subroutine

Tags: vb.net

```
Sub main() 

    Dim x as integer=5 

Sub add() 

End sub 

Sub add() 

    Dim z as integer = 5 + x  
    Console.writeline(z) 

End sub y
```

It will not work because I have to `Dim x` in the `sub add()` so what I want is a way to pass that value of `x` to the `sub add()`.

Comment: You need to study up on [Scope in VB](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33249045/1070452); the the very basic task of *passing parameters to methods*, all after you read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) to pass variables to a method like this :

```
Sub main() 
    Dim x as integer = 5
    add(x) 
End sub

Sub add(NewX As Integer) 
    Dim z as integer = 5 + NewX
    Console.writeline(z) 
End sub
```